# Наименование классов в c++

Tags: c++, классы

Я с другом веду разработку игры и мы недавно столкнулись с небольшой проблемой, которая перетекла в довольно большой спор.

Я начал разработку класса для обработки физики игры названный Physics и для этого класса я создал внутренний класс для описания физического объекта pObject который будет описывать физические законы для того или иного игрового объекта.

Выглядит это так:

```
class pObject
{
public:
   ...

   //описывает физические параметры объекта 
};
class Physics
{
private:
    std::vector<pObject> objects;
public:
    ...
    //Обрабатывает взаимодействие всех объектов
};
```

Вопрос заключается в том: Целесообразно ли использовать такое название класса с буквы нижнего регистра и с сокращением? ибо у моего друга знатно так с этого сгорело и как принято у всех, классы должны начинаться всегда с верхнего регистра

Comment: Нет единственного объективно верного ответа, так что этот вопрос [считается оффтопиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: А вообще, поместили бы `class pObject` внутрь `class Physics`. Тогда префикс не будет нужен. *"как принято у всех, классы должны начинаться всегда с верхнего регистра"* Вы это разработчикам стандарта с их стандартной библиотекой скажите. :)

Comment: Есть такое понятие - стиль :) Так вот, рекомендация одна - выберите для себя какой-то стиль и придерживайтесь его. Всё. Если работаете в команде - то используйте стиль, принятый командой. Ну не существует единого общепринятого стандарта, нельзя говорить, что надо так и только так. Если "так и только так" - это уже прописывается в стандарте языка.

Comment: А ещё лучше завернуть в анонимный namespace и будет хорошо. Но имя pObject у большинства людей вызовет подозрение - это очень похоже на имя указателя на Object.

Comment: Лучше дать логичное имя, например PhysicsObject, RigidBody и т.д.

Comment: Именуйте как угодно, главное, чтобы это именование было последовательным. Два имени, одно из которых начинается с прописной буквы, а другое со строчной вряд ли кем-то могут восприниматься как имена сущностей одного типа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На данный вопрос невозможно дать точный ответ. Однако, стоит учесть, что имя должно отражать назначение сущности. Я считаю, что имя типа `pObject` не удачное. Во-первых, с первого взгляда не понятно что такое `pObject`, во-вторых, в [венгеркой нотации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) префикс `p` означает, что это переменная указательного типа, и человека, знакомого с данной нотацией это может сбить с толку.

Возможно, вам просто нравится тратить уйму времени на споры "о прекрасном", но они существенно снижают эффективность вашей работы. Раз Вы с другом разрабатываете вместе, то необходимо утвердить единый стиль кода, конвенцию именования и т.д. Вы можете выработать собственные правила, а можете использовать уже имеющиеся, например [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide), а можете переделать их "под себя". Также вы можете инспектировать код друг друга, на предмет соблюдения стиля.

Вполне вероятно, что имеет смысл почитать книги соответствующей тематики, например,  книгу Стива Макконнелла "Совершенный код. Мастер-класс".